# Cannot use bluebird Promise IE11 webpack

Tags: promise, bluebird, webpack-3, webpack-plugin

I'm making an web app by using webpack, angularjs and bluebird.
I put this in my code:

```
{
"plugins":[
    {
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({Promise: 'bluebird'})
    }
  ]
}
```

But in developer console. Promise doesn't appear as a global variable. When I tried using it, console said: 'Promise is undefined'

[image]

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you,